# KB2829760, Fatal error during installation, Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2015, windows-7-x64, uninstallation

I am having some trouble installing Visual Studio Community 2015 on my laptop. It currently runs on Windows 7.

At first I was able to download it without any issues but then the trial period ran out and I wasn't able to log in to obtain a liciense. What I did instead was to try to uninstall Visual Studio and then reinstall it, in hopes that I can log in when it asks to in order to get the license. However, this did not go as plan and I had to remove it with other "methods".

Now I am trying to reinstall it but I keep getting a "fatal error during installation" message, which reads, "KB2829760, Fatal error during installation". I have attached the picture and my data log for my attempts at installation.

I have been through the registry, program files, program files x86, and uninstalled my previous versions of Visual Studio, which were not working by the way.

I need any help possible.

[Data log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qn07wwoiax9fmal/dd_vs_community_20151126050816.log?dl=0)

[KB2829760, Fatal error during installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdbzK.png)

Thank You All

Comment: same issue here, if you fixed it please tell us

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, I had 2 drives locked by bitlocker on my workstation, unlocking units allowed the installer to complete.

Looks like the installer is trying to access all of your drives, so my advice is to remove any mapped network drive that is not accessible and to unlock the bitlocker drives before to install visual studio (or kb2829760).